# LGBM handle categorical variable with categories which have quantities less than that of min_data_in_leaf

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

I am building a LGBM model where categorical features have been encoded using ordinal encoding. The categories get values from number from 1 to a max number that are all consecutive. How does LGBM handle categorical variable with categories which have quantities less than that of min_data_in_leaf?